# Why should postgresql.conf not be in the same dir as recovery.conf?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-replication

Apparently, I should put postgresql.conf in a separate directory, according to [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication):

```
# Note that recovery.conf must be in $PGDATA directory.
# It should NOT be located in the same directory as postgresql.conf
```

Is there any particular reason? I've seen systems where the two seem to work fine when they're both in the $PGDATA directory.

Answer (score 3):

This comment is meant to users who have `postgresql.conf` outside of `$PGDATA`. For instance Debian-based packages for PostgreSQL install the data directory inside `/var/lib/postgresql` and the configuration files inside `/etc/postgresql/`.

With that layout, some users could think of putting `recovery.conf` in the same directory than `postgresql.conf`, just because it's a config file too. But it's a mistake, it would be ignored.

To be less ambiguous, the second sentence could be:

```
# It should NOT be located in the same directory as postgresql.conf,
# unless that directory happens to be $PGDATA
```

Comment: YES! It certainly should say that, especially since the default configuration has postgresql.conf in $PGDATA